# How can I find the docker name from a program running inside Docker

Tags: docker

For logging purposes I want to know the name of the Docker instance that my program is running under.

For example if I start it as:

```
docker run -d --name my-docker-name some/image
```

how can i find the actual docker name (my-docker-name, in this example) from a program running in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: `--hostname` option.**

---

#### Issue

Container's program cannot access its container's name.

#### Solution a) -dirty and not easy-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36068029/5321002

#### Solution b)

Add the option `-h|--hostname=""` matching the same name as the docker container name. Then you just need to query the hostname from the program and you're done.

**edit**

#### Solution c)

Provide, as you suggested, a env-variable with the name. The overall command would look like as follow:

```
$name="custom-uniq-name"
$docker run -h $name --name $name -e NAME=$name image-to-run
```

Comment: Thanks, Maël this sound reasonable.  Not as reasonable as Docker providing a environment variable like it does for other values, but reasonable enough.  I'll wait a little longer if another solution is provided...

Comment: Solution (c) is the "prettiest" in my eyes, although I would agree that Docker should automatically pass this env variable as it does for all the other vals.

Answer (score 0):

if you add

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

to your

`docker run`

command, you expose docker socket to the container, and you will be able to launch docker commands, such as

`docker ps --filter`

Keep in mind that this is potentially dangerous, now your container has a privileged access to the host.

Comment: Too "dirty", sorry... :(